# Solving Simplified Hamilton's Equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, mathematical-physics

I have a question on a project that I am working on. I have included a large amount of the background information so that all relevant information is included, however the question is as follows (it is also #12 below):

> *Using a simplified version of $H$ given as $H(p,x)=\frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}$, consider a particle with initial position $a$ and no initial momentum. Solve Hamilton's equations for this particle. In other words, find the curve $\gamma(t)=(x(t),p(t))$ that solves Hamilton's equations with the initial conditions $x(0)=a$ and $p(0)=0$.*

**EDIT** This is the answer that I have given so far:

Using the example of the Harmonic Oscillator, with potential energy is $V(x) = \displaystyle\frac{kx^2}{2}$ for some constant $k$, and allowing $k$ and $m$ to be equal to $1$ for simplicity, the Hamiltonian is given by:
$$H(p,x) = \frac{p^2}{2} + \frac{x^2}{2}.$$
We can solve Hamilton's equations for a particle with initial position $a$ and no initial momentum, to find closed curve $\gamma(t)=(x(t),p(t))$, with $x(0)=a$ and $p(0)=0$.
In actuality, we are finding $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{p}$. Starting with the former, $\dot{x}$:

$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}
=\dot{x}
=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}
=\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\left(\frac{p^2}{2} + \frac{x^2}{2}\right)
=\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)
  + \frac{\partial}{\partial p}\left(\frac{p^2}{2}\right)
=0+\frac{2}{2}p
=p.$$

We now integrate $\displaystyle\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=p$ to get $x(t)$:
$$x(t)=\int{\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} dt} = \int{p dt} = pt + c_1.$$
Since we know $x(0)=a$, $a$ is the initial condition of $x(t)$, which implies $c_1=a$, giving $x(t)=pt+a$.
Similarly, we can find $p(t)$:

$$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}
=\dot{p}
=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}
=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{p^2}{2} +\frac{x^2}{2 }\right)
=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)
+ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{p^2}{2}\right)
=-\frac{2}{2}x+0=-x.
$$
We now integrate $\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=-x$ to get $p(t)$:

$$p(t)=\int{\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} dt} = \int{-x dt} = -xt + c_2.$$

Since we know $p(0)=0$, $0$ is the initial condition of $p(t)$, which implies $c_2=0$, giving $p(t)=-xt$.
Therefore, $\gamma(t)=(x(t),p(t))$ is given by the closed curve solving Hamilton's equations $\gamma(t)=\big(pt+a,-xt\big)$.

Here is the full information:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

$H = \dfrac{1}{2}(p^2 + x^2), \tag{1}$

we have

$\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial p} = p \tag{2}$

and

$\dfrac{\partial H }{\partial x} = x, \tag{3}$

so that Hamilton's equations become

$\dot x = \dfrac{\partial H}{\partial p} = p  \tag{4}$

and

$\dot p = -\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial x} = -x; \tag{5}$

we thus have

$\ddot x = \dot p = -x, \tag{6}$

or

$\ddot x + x = 0. \tag{7}$

The solutions of (7) take the general form

$x = A\sin t + B \cos t \tag{8}$

as is well-known.  From (8),

$p = \dot x = A\cos t - B\sin t, \tag{9}$

and we can find $A$ and $B$ by plugging in the initial conditions

$a = x(0) = A \sin 0 + B \cos 0 = B, \tag{10}$

$0 = p(0) = A \cos 0 - B \sin 0 = A. \tag{11}$

Thus

$x(t) = a\cos t, \tag{12}$

$p(t) = -a \sin t; \tag{13}$

the solution curve is

$\gamma(t) = (a\cos t, -a \sin t). \tag{14}$

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Thank you, but I did something a little differently. I got that $\dot{x}=p$ and $\dot{p}=-x$, but then I integrated those with respect to $t$, since $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=\dot{x}$ and similarly with $\dot{p}$. This gave me $\gamma(t)=\big(pt+a,-xt\big)$. Is this wrong?

Comment: Yes, the solution in your comment is in fact incorrect.  Since $x$ and $p$ depend on $t$, you can't assume x, $p$ are constant when you integrate $\dot x = p$ and $\dot p = -x$; the equations are coupled and thus must be solved together.  Also $H$ is the total energy and should be conserved.  But your solution yields $H = (1/2)((p^2 + x^2)t^2 + 2apt + a^2)$, not a constant.

Comment: Also, $\dot x= dx/dt$ is a total derivative, not a partial; you can't hold $p$ constant when you integrate the total derivative.  Hope these words clarify!

Comment: Here's more:  with $H$ as in my previous comment, $\dot x = (\partial H/\partial p) = pt^2 + at$, but your formula for $x$ yields $\dot x = p = -xt = -pt^2 - at$; inconsistent!